# How to copy os image cross IDC with softlayer API?

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a VM in IDC A, and I have captured this VM as my custom image_A. Now I want to copy image_A to IDC B. Does the softlayer API support this operation?

Comment: Please describe your question more clearly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To copy image across datacenters:

You can use:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::addLocations](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/addLocations)

Here an example using REST:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/$templateGroupId/addLocations

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      [  
         {  
            "id":1441195
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey**, **$templateGroupId** (image) with your own information. **1441195** refers to **Dallas 10** datacenter's identifier (You need to replace this with the datacenter's id, in which you wish to copy your image).

---

### To view your own block device template groups (images):

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups

Method: Get
```

**Method:** [SoftLayer_Account::getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups)

---

### To retrieve information from datacenters:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters

Method: Get
```

**Method:** [SoftLayer_Location::getDatacenters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters)

---

> **Updated**

### To retrieve locations containing a copy of an image

Try this:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/$templateGroupId/getDatacenters

Method: Get
```

**Method:** [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::getDatacenters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getDatacenters)

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. Perfectly solved my problem. But now other problem occurs: how to get the location(in which idc) of a private image. I have pulled the private image info by using Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group:getObject, result is like {'name': '3jingxian', 'createDate': '2016-07-21T17:16:51+08:00', 'blockDevices': [], 'globalIdentifier': 'xxx', 'parentId': '', 'id': 1252851, 'accountId': }.  As you can find that there is no location info...

Comment: Please, review the updated section in my answer, I hope it helps you, let me know any doubt or comments.